# How to bring Navigation Menu Items to be centered ? Wordpress Twenty Eleven

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to center my navigation menu but all my tries to do so are ending in the wrong direction...

[Project](http://iflorian.com/fwb_new/wordpress/)

This is my project and I'm trying to center my Navigation.

Any Idea how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `float` in your LI give `display:inline-block` to it. Like this:

```
.menu{
 text-align:center;
}
.menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;/* For IE7 */
    *zoom:1;/* For IE7 */
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: style.css line 567

```
#access ul {
    font-size: 18px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -0.8125em;
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

style.css line 573

```
#access li {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline-block; /* css hack to prevent from IE issues */
    position: relative;
}
```